# using xpath_table in postgresql?

Tags: database, postgresql, xpath, psql

There is table mydocs( id serial, docform int, content text).

```
SELECT * FROM 
  xpath_table('id','content','mydocs',
              '/tutorial/author|/tutorial/title',
              'true')
  AS t(id int, author text, title text, docform int)
```

i have (id, author and title, docform is 0/null) see in image

[image]

How to get docform from mydocs in select.

docform is column from table mydocs, like a said.

[image]

Comment: Please post sample of your XML structure and explain which part of the XML should be the `docform`

Comment: added image to post.
docform is column in mydocs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `docform` that you're trying to select come from a separate column the solution might need to be implemented outside `xpath_table()`, for example, by adding `JOIN` to `mydocs` table itself and get the `docform` from there :

```
SELECT t.*, m.docform 
  FROM mydocs m
  INNER JOIN LATERAL 
      xpath_table('id','content','mydocs',
                  '/tutorial/author|/tutorial/title',
                  'true')
      AS t(id int, author text, title text) ON m.id = t.id
```

**<kbd>[`sqlfiddle demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/427ce/1)</kbd>**